# How do I make a custom-created windows schedule task not run in background?

Tags: windows, task, scheduled-tasks

I've made a scheduled task that repeats itself each 4 hours. The task is that it starts a program that automatically will shutdown in 4 hours from start. But when I have windows task scheduler set to open the software each 4 hours, it just starts the process, not opening an actual window. How can I solve this?
The user is set to the useraccount I'm logged in to, not system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was basic: I had selected "Run even if user is logged off", meaning it'd run it all in another session or something like that. So I tried selecting "Run only if user is logged in" and it works like a charm! :)